# linux svn: Can't connect to host '': Connection refused

Tags: svn, connection, svnserve

The server restarted last night, since then I cannot do svn up or svn commit.
svn: Can't connect to host 'zillerserv': Connection refused

I did a fresh checkout in another folder, it worked.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: is svnserve running? Depending on where the server is, and how you connect, that service may need to be running.

Answer (score 2):

Enter this into the terminal:

```
svnserve -d -r /home/user/SVNREPO
```

where SVNREPO is your repository folder.

Comment: thanks @Mika. Didn't realize svnserve is not started.

Just to clarify:
`-d : run in daemon mode` , `-r : root of directory to serve`